# How playAtTime works? (swift in)

Tags: swift, nstimer, avaudioplayer, nstimeinterval

Using latest version of xcode and swift and iOS I'm trying to make an audioPlayer.
I have a NSTimer with interval 1 second which calculate the length of current audio, change minimum and maximum value of UISlider which is provided to implement playAtTime function and chang it's value. Like this:

```
let curTime: NSTimeInterval = a.musicPlayer.currentTime
        let dur: NSTimeInterval = a.musicPlayer.duration


        progress.minimumValue = 0
        progress.maximumValue = Float(dur)
        progress.value = Float(curTime)
```

In uiSliderValueChanged-action I've this:

```
let val: NSTimeInterval = double(uislider.value)
a.musicPlayer.playAtTime(val)
```

So when I'm testing it - nothing happening, audio continue playing and uislider value always sets to the current moment of playing audio. I tried to start and stop timer in `EditingDidBegin` and `-End`-actions - nothing changed. How can I use playAtTime correctly?

Comment: try a.musicPlayer.currentTime = Double(uislider.value)

Comment: thanks man, it's it! pity that I have not thought about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.musicPlayer.currentTime = Double(uislider.value)` –  **Leo Dabus**